# Android 8.1 Running CTS shows "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113"

Tags: android, cts

My OS of my computer is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I try to run CTS on an Android device and I have downloaded the following...
1. Platform tools
2. OpenJDK8
3. Android 8.1 R18 Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) - ARM
4. CTS Media 1.4

While running cts, it shows messages below...

> 04-21 17:44:03 I/ResultReporter: Invocation finished in 1m 2s. PASSED:
>   12, FAILED: 0, MODULES: 8 of 468 04-21 17:44:03 E/CommandScheduler:
>   com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError: Failed to install
>   CtsDebugTestCases.apk on 173215230D5019. Reason:
>   'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries,
>   res=-113' [173215230D5019 qcom:MC33 01-09-17.00-OG-U00-STD]
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError: Failed to install
>   CtsDebugTestCases.apk on 173215230D5019. Reason:
>   'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries,
>   res=-113' [173215230D5019 qcom:MC33 01-09-17.00-OG-U00-STD]

I have tried to install the apk via ADB manually by the following command...
adb install -r android-cts/testcases/CtsDebugTestCases.apk
It is successful.

I unzipped the apk, there are 2 folders "arm64-v8a" and "armeabi-v7a" in the path CtsDebugTestCases.apk_FILES/lib/. I think the apk is no problem.

I have no idea about this problem. Anyone can help?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it seems that I solved this problem.
In the path "android-cts/testcases/", open the CtsDebugTestCases.config file.
Modify the string from

```
com.android.tradefed.targetprep.suite.SuiteApkInstaller
```

to

```
com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.ApkInstaller
```

It works when I run cts again.

You can also use the command below to modify all the config files.

```
sed -i 's/com.android.tradefed.targetprep.suite.SuiteApkInstaller/com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.ApkInstaller/g' *.config
```